# Use the Reduce command to obtain the value range of Δt

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I used the following code in Mathematica to calculate the value range of *Δt*, but running the code failed to obtain the correct result. I would like to ask how to modify my code.

A system of inequalities contains two parts：

$$-1/2Δt(X'(t+Δt)-X'(t))<=1/2000$$

$$0<=t<=2/25$$

Where $X(t)=23.999999999999996 + 
 55.082039324993595 E^(-267.92850868181444t)- 
 79.08203932499359 E^(-186.61694586364015 t)$

I tried to write two forms of code, but neither of them ran correctly and got results.

The first form：

```
X = 23.999999999999996` + 
   55.082039324993595` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
   79.08203932499359` E^(-186.61694586364015` t);
DX = D[X, t];
Subscript[DX, n + 1] = ReplaceAll[DX, t -> t + \[EmptyUpTriangle]t];
Reduce[{-1/2*\[EmptyUpTriangle]t*(Subscript[DX, n + 1] - DX) <= 
   1/2000, 0 <= t <= 2/25}, {\[EmptyUpTriangle]t, t}]
```

The second form：

```
X = 23.999999999999996` + 
   55.082039324993595` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
   79.08203932499359` E^(-186.61694586364015` t);
DX = D[X, t];
Subscript[DX, n + 1] = ReplaceAll[DX, t -> t + \[EmptyUpTriangle]t];
Reduce[ForAll[t, 
  Element[t, {t, 0, 2/25}]], -1/
    2*\[EmptyUpTriangle]t*(Subscript[DX, n + 1] - DX) <= 
  1/2000, \[EmptyUpTriangle]t, Reals]
```

Thank you for your advice and assistance！

**Update my questions！**

Now I am using the method shown to me by the following gentleman for drawing (the drawing area includes two parts: *il* and *vc*). Can I obtain the global maximum or global minimum value of *dt* in the two parts of the drawing area?

The code:

```
il = Function[t, 
   23.999999999999996` + 
    55.082039324993595` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    79.08203932499359` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
vc = Function[t, 
   1.0909090909090908` + 
    1.0279241950771227` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 
    2.118833285986214` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)];
cond1 = -1/2 dt (il'[t + dt] - il'[t]) <= 1/2000;
cond2 = -1/2 dt (vc'[t + dt] - vc'[t]) <= 1/2000;
RegionPlot[{cond1, cond2}, {t, 0, 2/25}, {dt, 0, 0.5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {t, dt}]
maxil = Maximize[{dt, cond1, 0 <= t <= 2/25, 0 <= dt <= 0.5}, {t, 
   dt}]
maxvc = Maximize[{dt, cond2, 0 <= t <= 2/25, 0 <= dt <= 0.5}, {t, dt}]
```

Running results：

[image]

Comment: What is `e`? Mathematica uses `E` for the Euler's number.

Comment: @Syed Excuse me, sir. I'll edit it again.

Comment: @Syed Hello, sir! I corrected my formula for **X(t)**, which is equal to the sum of these series of exponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X=Exp
Reduce[-1/2 dt (X'[t + dt] - X'[t]) < 1/2000 && 0 <= t <= 2/25 &&dt > 0]
(*dt > 0 && 0 <= t <= 2/25*)
```

For positive `dt` your condition is true in the given range of `t`

**modified**

Surprisingly QP changed definition of X

```
X = Function[t, 23.999999999999996` + 55.082039324993595` E^(-267.92850868181444` t) - 79.08203932499359` E^(-186.61694586364015` t)]
```

`Reduce` isn't able to simplify connditon but `RegionPlot` gives an idea  of the solution range

```
cond = -1/2 dt (X'[t + dt] - X'[t]) < 1/2000
RegionPlot[cond, {t, 0, 2/25}, {dt, 0, .01}, FrameLabel -> {t, dt}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, sir! I corrected my formula for **X(t)**, which is equal to the sum of these series of exponents. And I tried your method. When **X(t)** equals the formula of the sum of these exponents, it cannot be calculated correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask what the word **cond** in the code means？

Comment: Sorry , forgot to paste the definition...See my modified answer!

Comment: Sir, it's okay haha, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sir, can I find the maximum or minimum value of *dt* in the drawing area? I have updated the details in the original question.

Comment: Try `NMinimize`: `mini = NMinimize[{dt^2, -1/2 dt (X'[t + dt] - X'[t]) == 1/2000 , 
   0 < t < 2/25, .01 > dt > 0}, {t, dt}] ` which  gives `{6.25769*10^-9, {t -> 0.00885919, dt -> 0.0000791056}}`

Comment: When I used the NMaximize command to calculate *il*, which is the maximum value of the blue curve in the above image, I obtained the result: {0.5, {t -> 0.08, dt -> 0.5}}. And the system prompts **Maximize: Unable to converge to the required accuracy or precision in 100 generations**. In fact, shouldn't the maximum value of the blue curve be around *0.2* (as shown in the above image)?

Comment: I have updated the latest code above.

Comment: Maximum of the blue curve is at t==0 or t==2/25 I think. NMaximum tries to find numerically th global maximum

Comment: Sorry sir, I didn't express myself clearly haha. I am referring to the blue curve of the image I uploaded, and indeed the maximum value of the blue curve should be obtained at t==0 or t=2/25. From the curve observation, the maximum value should be around **0.2**, but the maximum value I calculated using NMaximum is 0.5. The code and graph were just uploaded by me, you can take a look.

Comment: Astonishing!!! Try `maxil = NMaximize[{dt Boole[cond1], {cond1, 0 <= t <= 2/25, 
    0 <= dt   }}, {t, dt}]`

Comment: Successful sir, thank you! But what is **Boole**'s role here?

Comment: When I used this method to calculate maxvc, _maxvc = NMaximize[{dt Boole[cond2], {cond2, 0 <= t <= 2/25, 
    0 <= dt}}, {t, dt}]_ the maximum value of *dt* was not calculated correctly again, which is really a headache. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Try `maxvc = NMaximize[{dt Boole[cond2], cond2, 0 <= t <= 2/25, 
   0 <= dt <= 0.5}, {t, dt}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
`